# How do I get one to many/foreign key to work in django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Here is the code I've written:

**models.py:**

```
class Name_overall(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Name_state(models.Model):  
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    name_overall = models.ForeignKey(Name_overall, db_column='name')
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.state
```

**views.py:**

```
def single_name(request, baby_name):
    baby_list = get_list_or_404(Name_overall, name=baby_name)
    return render_to_response('names/single_name.html', {'baby_list': baby_list})
```

**single_name.html:**

```
{{ baby_list.name_state_set.all }}
```

Nothing shows up in the single_name.html template. If I change it to {{ baby_list }}, there is an object there, but I am not able to access the Name_state class. I thought I should be able to have access to Name_state because of the foreign key. What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but if your state field is meant to hold a US state's code, you may want to use django.contrib.localflavor.us.models.USStateField instead of an explicit CharField with limited choices. For Australia, there's a predefined constant STATE_CHOICES in django.contrib.localflavor.au.au_states, and there's a bunch of other local flavours to look up if you're somewhere else still. Keeping constants of this kind in one place and just reusing them seems like good practice to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `baby_list` context variable is a QuerySet. You need to iterate it and access the ForeignKey in the loop.

```
{% for item in baby_list %}
  {{item.name_state_set.all}}
  #iterate the name_state_set
  {% for obj in item.name_state_set.all %}
    {{obj}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```